# Global variables in a Solana program

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, rust, solana-cli

Is it possible to create global mutable variables in a Solana program? I want to have a global mutable variable that stores some integer, and I'm getting a compilation error when doing so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rust typically doesn't use global variables, except for constants, because of its memory management model.

In Solana, variables can't persist between instructions anyways, so a variable that's in scope in an instruction handler is about as global as it gets.